# What's up with Bob Taylor in Prisoners (2013)?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners

I never really understood the character of Bob Taylor in Prisoners - his motives and why he is important to the story at all.

- Firstly, for some reason, he is attracted to children's toys and clothing. At the candlelight vigil, we can see him gently stroking a teddy bear, almost like a child. He buys children's clothing at the mall.
- Secondly, he breaks into people's houses to steal the children's clothes. Not to mention, he soaks them in pig's blood.
- Thirdly, he is a maze fanatic who has snakes in his house.
- He even confesses the abductions/ murders of the girls.

I didn't really get this man's motif. He is not even responsible or has anything to do with the abductions, so how does he lead our protagonists to Mrs. Holly's house? I understand that he was abducted by Mrs. Holly, but that still doesn't explain how he contributed to solving the mystery? And what's with the clothing fetish and the mazes and the snakes? Mrs. Holly does mention Alex's "snake accident", but how is that related to Bob Taylor's snakes at all? And why does he confess to the abductions?

Now, I understand I'm asking way too many questions in one post and am technically breaking the SE rules. So answer this one question:

**What's up with Bob Taylor in this movie?**